# openpyxl iterate through specific columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
for row_cells in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=8):
    for cell in row_cells:
        print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value))
```

The above snippet returns all the columns starting from column 1 up to column 8. I only need values from these two columns.
Is it possible to get **column 1 and 8 only**? I'm not able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't obligated to have the inner loop:

```
for row_cells in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=8):
    print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (row_cells[0], row_cells[0].value))
    print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (row_cells[-1], row_cells[-1].value))
```

A better approach might be to zip the iterators over just those two columns:

```
for c1, c8 in zip(sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1), sheet.iter_rows(min_col=8, max_col=8)):
    print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (c1, c1.value))
    print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (c8, c8.value))
```

Comment: Worked! Quite straightforward.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
for row in range(2,worksheet.max_row+1):  
for column in [column_3_name, column_8_name]:
    cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
    process(worksheet[cell_name].value)  # Process it
```

Beware this is heavy on memory, allocating memory for each cell. See:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/tutorial.html (especially first warning).

I would choose to do what you are doing currently:

```
for row_cells in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=8):
    for cell in row_cells:
        # Check for column name here.
```

Comment: Yes, as you have mentioned in the comment "Check for column name here". That's what I'll try to do now. Something like, give me the value for a cell belonging to a particular column only. Actually, I just started working on Python and openpyxl since last 2 days.
Something like...
cell['A'] + cell ['H'] that would only return the cell values from column A and H.

Comment: You should never used `ws[]` inside a loop. The cell, iter_rows and iter_cols methods exist for programmatic access.