# How to write .xlsx data to a .txt file ensuring each column has its own text file, then each row is a new line?

Tags: python-3.x, path, openpyxl

I believe I am close to cracking this however I can't add multiple lines of text to the .txt files. The column do relate to their own .txt files.

```
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path

# create workbook
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

listOfTextFiles = []

# Create a workbook 5x5 with dummy text
for row in range(1, 6): 
    for col in range(1, 6):
        file = sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value = f'text row:{row}, col:{col}'
        
        listOfTextFiles.append(file)
print(listOfTextFiles) # for testing
wb.save('testSS.xlsx')

for i in range(row): # create 5 text files
        textFile = open(f'ssToTextFile{i}.txt', 'w')
        textFile.write(listOfTextFiles[i])
```

The output for each text file is below. I know it has something to do with the 'textFile.write(listOfTextFiles[i])' and I've tried many ways such as replacing [i] with [j] or [file]. I think I am overwriting the text through each loop.

Current output:
ssToTextFile.txt -> text row:1, col:1

What I want the output to be in each .txt file:
ssToTextFile.txt -> text row:1, col:1 
text row:2, col:1 
text row:3, col:1 
text row:4, col:1 
text row:5, col:1

Then, the next .txt file to be: 
text row:1, col:2 
text row:2, col:2 etc

Would appreciate any feedback and the logic behind it please?

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335083/openpyxl-iterate-through-specific-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Using sheet.columns on the outer loop I could use [x-1] as the index.

```
for x in range(sheet.min_row, sheet.max_row + 1):
    textFile = open(f'ssToTextFile{x-1}.txt', 'w')
    for y in list(sheet.columns)[x-1]:
        textFile.write(str(y.value)+ '\n')
        print(y.value)
```